# Refresh vs. Update

Tags: word-choice, technology

I need some advice on the use of these two words - update and refresh.

I am currently working on the desktop app and I need to give a button a correct name.
There is a big number of objects that an app stores in the database and multiple users can work with them simultaneously. If one user changes an object, it gets changed for all the other users. And this button can disable or enable this function.

I consider two names. Data Auto Refresh and Data Auto Update. Which sounds more native? And is there any significant difference between these words?

Comment: In IT "refresh" is usually used to mean that the objects are returned to their original state rather than being updated to a new state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, "update" means to modify or replace something with a newer version or to change it to match a newer version. Like if you say, "Sally updated her refrigerator", you'd be understood to mean that she either bought a new refrigerator to replace her old one, or possibly that she had her refrigerator modified to incorporate some newer features.

In IT, "update" can mean that, like, "I updated from Windows 10 to Windows 11". Or it can mean to write new data to your data base (or whatever data storage). Like, "I updated the postal code file with new data from the post office."

"Refresh" generally means to restore something to its previous condition. Like, "I was exhausted from the long run but after a long drink of water I was refreshed." I was back to my normal condition.

In IT, it usually means to get a new, good copy of data or code. Like, "After the hard drive failed, we refreshed the system from a backup."

Personally, I wouldn't use either word in this case. I'd say "synchronize". As in, "Synchronize my data with other users' data."

Either "update" or "refresh" would be arguably correct. But, to me at least, I'd take "auto update" to mean that any changes I make will automatically be written to the database without having to take some extra step -- clicking a "save" button or perhaps something more complex. I'd take "auto refresh" to mean that, under some circumstances, changes I made would be thrown out and the previous data would be restored. (I'd expect some explanation somewhere of just what those circumstances are.)

It's common to talk about insuring that data is the same across multiple systems or users as "synchronizing".

Answer (score 2):

**Refresh** is the better choice for re-fetching rows from the database in case your local disconnected recordset contains "stale" rows. **Update** would imply a write in the context of a database application, saving any changes made on the client back to the database